# FMX app crash when TLocationSensor active

Tags: android, delphi, gps, firemonkey

Delphi 10.3, Android API: 28, Phone: Samsung Galaxy A52S 5G

I have create a Blank FMX Application. The LocationSensor only the form. (Active := True)
User permission added: Access coarse location and Acces fine location

On phone GPS active.

- If run the Application, and no Location permission, OK, not crashed! LocationSensor not Active
- If the phone add Location permission (Always), and not use of accurate location, OK, not crashed! LocationSensor not Active
- If the phone add Location permission (Always), and use of accurate location, Not OK, crashed, but LocationSensor is Active!

What's the problem?

This is code:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
  FMX.Types, FMX.Controls, FMX.Forms, FMX.Graphics, FMX.Dialogs, FMX.Controls.Presentation,
  FMX.StdCtrls, System.Sensors, System.Sensors.Components;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    LocationSensor1: TLocationSensor;
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.fmx}
```

Comment: Are you requesting the permissions at runtime? Please see [this](http://blong.com/Articles/AndroidPermissions/DelphiAppPermissions.htm)

Comment: Also your Facebook post mentions the device has Android 12, which is not API level 28 (Android 9). There were changes in Android 12 that are not supported by Delphi 10.3. The easiest way to solve the crash is to upgrade to Delphi 11.3

Answer (score 0):

I can't help you with the LocationSensor component, because I only ever tried it early in my first Android development. However, you can implement GPS functionality using the API. Don't call `StartAndroidGps` until the app has 'settled' and the UI becomes active. eg. after user login.

```
uses
  , Androidapi.JNI.Provider
  , Androidapi.JNI.JavaTypes
  , Androidapi.Helpers
  , Androidapi.JNI.Location
  , Androidapi.JNIBridge
  , FMX.Helpers.Android
  , Androidapi.JNI.GraphicsContentViewText
  , Androidapi.JNI.Net
  , AndroidApi.JNI.Embarcadero
  , Androidapi.JNI.Os
  , System.Android.Sensors 
  , System.Android.Service

private
    FLocationManager : JLocationManager;
    locationListener : TLocationListener;
    procedure LocationisChanged(location: JLocation);
    procedure StartAndroidApi;
    procedure StopAndroidApi;

  TLocationListener = class(TJavaLocal, JLocationListener)
  private
    [weak]
    FParent : TfrmTabbed;
  public
    constructor Create(AParent : TfrmTabbed);
    procedure onLocationChanged(location: JLocation); cdecl;
    procedure onProviderDisabled(provider: JString); cdecl;
    procedure onProviderEnabled(provider: JString); cdecl;
    procedure onStatusChanged(provider: JString; status: Integer; extras: JBundle); cdecl;
  end;
```

...

```
procedure TfrmTabbed.StartAndroidGPS;
var
  LocationManagerService: JObject;
  location : JLocation;
begin

  if not Assigned(FLocationManager) then
  begin
    LocationManagerService := TAndroidHelper.Context.getSystemService(TJContext.JavaClass.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    FLocationManager := TJLocationManager.Wrap((LocationManagerService as ILocalObject).GetObjectID);
    if not Assigned(locationListener) then
      locationListener := TLocationListener.Create(self);
  end;

  FLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(TJLocationManager.JavaClass.GPS_PROVIDER,
      15000, 30, locationListener,
        TJLooper.JavaClass.getMainLooper); // see the Android doc's

  // just to get started, ask for Last Known Location if any
  LogMe('GPS started');
  location := FLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(TJLocationManager.JavaClass.GPS_PROVIDER);
  LocationisChanged(location);

end;

procedure TfrmTabbed.StopAndroidGPS;
begin
  LogMe('GPS stopped');
  if Assigned(locationListener) then
    FLocationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
end;

{ TLocationListener }

constructor TLocationListener.Create(AParent: TfrmTabbed);
begin
  inherited Create;
  FParent := AParent;
end;

procedure TLocationListener.onLocationChanged(location: JLocation);
begin
  FParent.LocationisChanged(location);
end;

procedure TLocationListener.onProviderDisabled(provider: JString);
begin
end;

procedure TLocationListener.onProviderEnabled(provider: JString);
begin
end;

procedure TLocationListener.onStatusChanged(provider: JString; status: Integer;
  extras: JBundle);
begin
end;

procedure TfrmTabbed.LocationisChanged(location: JLocation);
begin

  if FisClosing then
    EXIT; // the code causes an AV if the app is already closing

  if Assigned(location) then
  begin
    // Calling the LocationSensor's method :-)
    LocationSensor1LocationChanged(Self,
      TLocationCoord2D.Create(0,0),
      TLocationCoord2D.Create(location.getLatitude, location.getLongitude))
  end;

end;
```